# Поиск в TableView

Tags: xcode, swift

помогите, уважаемые знатоки! При выборе пункта в TableView осуществляется переход во View Controller с определенным текстом. Добавила Serch, при поиске выбираю пункт, однако переход не осуществляется, что делать?

import UIKit

class KoAPTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

```
var tableArray = ["Статья 1.4. Принцип равенства перед законом","Статья 1.5. Презумпция невиновности","Статья 2.1. Административное правонарушение","Статья 2.3. Возраст, по достижении которого наступает административная ответственность","Статья 2.6.1. Административная ответственность собственников (владельцев) транспортных средств","Статья 2.9. Возможность освобождения от административной ответственности при малозначительности административного правонарушения","Статья 4.1. Общие правила назначения административного наказания","татья 4.2. Обстоятельства, смягчающие административную ответственность","Статья 4.3. Обстоятельства, отягчающие административную ответственность","Статья 4.4. Назначение административных наказаний за совершение нескольких административных правонарушений","Статья 4.5. Давность привлечения к административной ответственности","Статья 4.6. Срок, в течение которого лицо считается подвергнутым административному наказанию","Статья 20.1. Мелкое хулиганство","Статья 20.20. Потребление (распитие) алкогольной продукции в запрещенных местах","Статья 20.21. Появление в общественных местах в состоянии опьянения","Статья 27.9. Досмотр транспортного средства","Статья 27.12. Отстранение от управления транспортным средством, освидетельствование на состояние алкогольного опьянения и медицинское освидетельствование на состояние опьянения","Статья 27.12.1. Медицинское освидетельствование на состояние опьянения","Статья 27.13. Задержание транспортного средства","Статья 28.5. Сроки составления протокола об административном правонарушении","Статья 28.6. Назначение административного наказания без составления протокола","Статья 29.5. Место рассмотрения дела об административном правонарушении","Статья 29.6. Сроки рассмотрения дела об административном правонарушении","Статья 29.7. Порядок рассмотрения дела об административном правонарушении","Статья 31.9. Давность исполнения постановления о назначении административного наказания","Статья 32.7. Исчисление срока лишения специального права"]
var segueIdentifieres = ["AA","AB","AC"]
var searchController = UISearchController()
var resultsController = UITableViewController()
var filterArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
    resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self

}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterArray = tableArray.filter({ (array:String) -> Bool in
        if array.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
    resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if tableView == resultsController.tableView {
        return filterArray.count
    } else {
        return tableArray.count
    }

}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView == resultsController.tableView {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filterArray[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifieres [indexPath.row], sender: self)
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно добавлять еще один  TableViewController в свойства, это лишнее. 
У меня массивы с данными (фильтрованными и не фильтрованными) содержатся в модели, а не в контроллере, но это не меняет сути. Обратите внимание на функцию isFiltering, которая и есть флаг из какого массива брать данные, с фильтром или исходного:

```
class ContactsListViewController: UITableViewController {

  let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      title = "CONTACTS"
      tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
      setupTopBar()
  }

  func setupTopBar() {
      navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
      searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
      navigationItem.searchController = searchController
      searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
  }
}

extension ContactsListViewController {

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      if isFiltering() {
          return 1
      }
      return ContactsManager.shared.headerTitles.count
  }

  override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) ->     [String]? {
      let stringTitles = ContactsManager.shared.headerTitles.map {   String($0) }
      return stringTitles
  }


  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      if isFiltering() {
          return 0
      }
      return 30.0
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return 69.0
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if isFiltering() {
          return ContactsManager.shared.filteredContacts.count
      }
      let key = ContactsManager.shared.headerTitles[section]
      return ContactsManager.shared.tableViewSource[key]!.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactsCell") as! ContactsCell
      let contact: ContactData
      if isFiltering() {
          contact = ContactsManager.shared.filteredContacts[indexPath.row]
      } else {
          let key =   ContactsManager.shared.headerTitles[indexPath.section]
          let contacts = ContactsManager.shared.tableViewSource[key]!
          contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
      }
      cell.nameTitle.text = contact.longName
      if let imageData = contact.thumbnailImageData {
           cell.anImageView.image = UIImage.init(data: imageData)
      } else {
          cell.anImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "avatar_small")
      }
      return cell
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
      tableView.allowsSelection = false
      callToContact(contactIndexPath: indexPath)
  }

  func callToContact(contactIndexPath: IndexPath) {
      ...
  }

  func requestForContact(number: String, contactData: ContactData) {
      ...
  }
}
extension ContactsListViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {

  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
      filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
  }

  func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
      // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
      return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
  }

  func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
      ContactsManager.shared.filteredContacts = ContactsManager.shared.contacts.filter({( contact : ContactData) -> Bool in
          return   contact.longName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
      })
      tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func isFiltering() -> Bool {
      return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
  }
}
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло(( результаты поиска выводит, однако при нажатии открываются позиции находящиеся на первом окне - "под" результатами поиска, как сделать активным окно с поиском, чтобы при нажатии открывались именно данные из окна поиска?

Comment: потому что при нажатии данные надо извлекать из массива с отфильтрованными данными, то есть в didSelectRow atIndexPath (или в prepairForSeque) надо проверять if isFiltering() возвращает true то данные брать из фильтрованного, если нет, то из полного массива.

Comment: у меня есть это метод, но почему же он не работает ? override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifieres [indexPath.row], sender: self)
}. как сюда включить проверку if isFilrering, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ирина, ещё раз теория: в контролере, создающемся при performSegue вам надо взять какие то данные и заполнить UI (labels, images, etc). Для того что бы понять какие именно данные брать вы передаете indexPath.row, то есть индекс по которому будут доставаться данные из какого то массива. Из какого? Если включена фильтрация, из массива с отфильтрованными данными, если не включена - из исходного массива, со всеми данными. У вас же есть массив, который содержит данные при фильтрации?

Comment: Признаюсь честно - я очень слаба в теории (да и в практике=), пытаюсь сделать по что-то видеоурокам. Делаю зеркало андройд приложения. Как я понимаю -  в prepairForSeque необходима ссылка на  второй view controller, а у меня их очень много и переход осуществляется по segueIdentifieres. Все уроки заканчиваются на результатах поиска, однако реализация перехода по выбранному результату нигде не показана

Comment: Вам надо ещё позаниматься, я на самом деле не советую видеоуроки, потому что темп восприятия и урока может сильно различаться и вы потеряете время, лучше ищите письменные примеры и лучше на английском, там информация чище и ее на порядки больше